# How do you calculate the opposite of a probability

Tags: bayes-theorem

Given this problem:

Suppose prior probabilities in a decision situation are P(S1) = 0.2, P(S2) = 0.5, and P(S3) = 0.3. With sample information I, P(I/S1) = 0.1, P(I/ S2) = 0.05 and P(I/ S3) = 0.2. Calculate the revised or posterior probabilities: P(S1/I), P(S2/I) and P(S3/I).

My question is

If P(S1) = 0.2, what is the opposite P(S1`)?

and

If P(I/S1) = 0.1, what is the opposite P(I/S1`)?

I am hesitant because we've never done this in class with 3 probabilities.  We have always done it with 2.  Is P(S1`) = P(S2) + P(S3)?  And is P(I/S1`) = P(I/S2) + P(I/S3)?

Answer (score 0):

If $S_1,\ldots,S_n$ are disjoint events, the *law of total probability* says $$
  P(I) = \sum_{k=1}^n P(I \mid S_k)P(S_k)
$$
and the *bayesian theorem* says $$
  P(S_k \mid I) = \frac{P(I \mid S_k)P(S_k)}{P(I)} \text{.}
$$
Combining the two yields $$
  P(S_k \mid I) = \frac{p_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n p_k} \text{ where } p_k = P(I \mid S_k)P(S_k) \text{.}
$$

Comment: so in my case scenario can we say that 
P(I) = P(I|S1) P(S1) + P(I|S2) P(S2) + P(I|S3) P(S3)?

Comment: @RamonSaguna The answer is *right there* in the last line. In your case, you have $S_1,S_2,S_3$, so the number of disjoint events you start with is $n=3$.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help..the problem is with me not with you :<

Comment: @RamonSaguna Are things clear to you now?

Comment: Clear no, but the reason is that I am not very familiar with the mathematical syntax you use even though it is universal.  It's because the probabilities and theories have been thought to us in a very short span of 30 minutes with many assumptions that we (the students) were already familiar to probabilities.  But at the time I was still at school, probabilities were not part of the syllabus so they are brand new.  Anyway what I know is that the E symbol means that its the sum and this is why I asked if P(I) = P(I|S1)P(S1) + P(I|S2)P(S2) + P(I|S3)P(S3).  If this is so, I can answer the quest

Comment: @RamonSaguna Hm, I fear that if you're not familiar with the basic concepts, then trying to explain the bayesian theorem or posterior probabilities is probably fruitless... I think you'll need to start at the beginning. You might want to search around this site for suggestions on good introductory texts on the subject, or post a reference-request question about this.